# Djago time widget not showing up

Tags: django, time, widget

All I want to do is add time widget to my form so I can easily pick the time. Everything is very simple, the page is loading but the widgets don't show up. No error nothing. I am thinking maybe I didn't set up the form widgets correctly but not sure what I did wrong. Here is my Forms.py-

```html
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget, AdminTimeWidget, AdminSplitDateTime

class WorkOutForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOut
        fields = '__all__'   
        widgets={
            'start':AdminTimeWidget(),
            'end':AdminTimeWidget(),

        }
```

Here is the Models.py. You will notice "start" and "end" fields are timefield-

```html
class WorkOut(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    day=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    start=models.TimeField(null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=move)
    weight=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    rep=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    pedal= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)  
    stretchtype =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    end=models.TimeField(null=True)
    note=models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here are the views linked to it even though I don't think it has much relevance-

```html
def workout(request):
    form=WorkOutForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=WorkOutForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context={'form':form}   

    return render(request, 'myapp/enter_workout.html', context)  


 

def update_workout(request, pk):
    order=WorkOut.objects.get(id=pk)
    form=WorkOutForm(instance=order)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=WorkOutForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            
    context={'form':form}

    return render(request, 'myapp/enter_workout.html', context)
```

And the form on HTML page is also very basic,so don't think there is any issue there either-

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
           
            {{form}}
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
        </form>
```

What have I done wrong here? How can I make those widgets to show up?

Comment: you do not display start, end, they are visible to me, but date, day are not visible? If exactly date, day are not visible, then my answer is below

Comment: Actually start and end, the two time fields are not working as expected. Everything else, including date and day are working fine is my original code. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: How are they supposed to work?

Comment: I am trying to add the pictures, it won't let me. Picture would have made it clear. Django has this built in time and date widget that I am trying to add. They should appear on my html page (where the form is) right beside the respective fields  . In my case the fields are start and end. And those widgets are not showing up. Those widgets help you to click and choose time. They also have a similar date widget, but I do not need it here.

Comment: This is how they look in the admin panel?

Comment: Those widgets, they show up on the django template, where I show the form, not on the admin panel.

Comment: This I know. I just want to understand what it should look like. You can see them in the admin panel. Do you need the current time to be filled in these fields or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly that. As you see this is a workout related model. So every other field can a filled whenever. But when someone is ready to to do the workout they can enter current time to the start field and at the end enter the current time to the end field. That is the goal.

Comment: Made, that in fields start, end there was a current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to fill the default values with the current time.

```
from datetime import datetime


class WorkOut(models.Model):
    move = (("1", "Tom"), ("2", "Sara"), ("3", "Emilia"),)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    day = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
    start = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=move)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    rep = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    pedal = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    stretchtype = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    end = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now,null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Update 22.10.2022**
Made fields with time selection on bootstrap.
For this you need to install:

```
pip install django-bootstrap4
pip install django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus
```

In the WorkOutForm class in **init** set the styles for all fields.

forms.py

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import TimePickerInput

class WorkOutForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOut
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "start": TimePickerInput(),
            "end": TimePickerInput(),

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkOutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                "class": "form-control"
            })
```

templates

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{{ form.media }}

<form action="" method="POST" style="width: 20%">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: This won't look perfect but it might get the job done for now if that time updates on every form submit/save function. Then I might be able to use the update button and update time for each instance. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: If you refresh the page, the time changes and after sending it also changes. Not sure if I can do it. Do you still need a forced time update button on the form? But here's the thing. Let's say you updated the time, but while you moved the cursor to the send button, it will be different, for a few seconds. Time fields can also be edited.

Comment: @user19637275 where did you see a working version with AdminTimeWidget()? All that I found was with bindings to javascript.

Comment: I was ready to compromise those few seconds it takes to move cursor to the send button, it was a valid concern though. That is why my first attempt was to trigger it from the view, not the widget. And I am going back to try that. In your suggested way the problem I will face is that if the time updates at page refresh, it won't work. It will keep changing the original start and end time at every page load. And I think we are both talking about the one with JS. Thanks for your input and I will try again the views based time stamp (didn't work the first time) and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: "It will keep changing the original start and end time at every page load" and "I was ready to compromise those few seconds it takes to move cursor to the send button, it was a valid concern though" . What do you really need!? One contradicts the other.

Comment: My end goal is populate the "start" and "end" fields with a time when a button is clicked. I tried to do it by triggering views.py at a button click, had challenges. So I thought about this time widget, which does the job, even though it is a less desirable solution. And as you know, the widget never showed up with the above code. I have to make one of these work so I can populate time fields with a button click.

Comment: @user19637275 updated answer with bootstrap applied, what you want.